# How to convert MySQL Timestamp to Javascript date?

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-visualization, jstl

I want to display a Google Chart (Line Chart) on .jsp page of my Spring MVC application. The data is retrieved from a MySQL database, so I need to convert the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format into Javascript's Date.

The database is created by Hibernate. The `Reading` entity has a `time` field of type `java.sql.Timestamp`, which is stored as `DATETIME` in the database.

The `results` is an `Iterable<Reading>` object passed to the .jsp via controller. It is passed correctly (I am displaying the data as a table, too).

I'm trying to use the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075577/convert-mysql-datetime-stamp-into-javascripts-date-format), but it does not work.

Here's the code I'm trying to populate the chart with:

```
<c:forEach items="${results}" var="reading">
    var t = "${reading.time}".split(/[- :]/);
    var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
    data.addRow([d,${reading.temperature}]);
</c:forEach>
```

The chart is not displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facts:

- JDBC's [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) is a subclass of [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).
- JSTL has a [`<fmt:formatDate>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) for converting `java.util.Date` to `String`.
- JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor can take a.o. a string in ISO8601 time format.

Put together:

```html
<c:forEach items="${results}" var="reading">
    <fmt:formatDate var="time" value="${reading.time}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" timeZone="UTC" />
    var d = new Date("${time}");
    // ...
</c:forEach>
```

Alternatively, just convert `results` to JSON using a decent JSON formatter in the controller and print it as if it's a JS variable like so `var data = ${data};`. See also a.o. [How to access array of user defined objects within <script> in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092675/how-to-access-array-of-user-defined-objects-within-script-in-jsp/)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: make sure your model is of `java.util.Date` type. You shouldn't have `java.sql.*` typed properties in your model. If you're using plain JDBC, just upcast `ResultSet#getTimestamp()` to `java.util.Date` directly. See also a.o. [Handling MySQL datetimes and timestamps in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323618/handling-mysql-datetimes-and-timestamps-in-java/).

Comment: Thank you for the hints and the answer. However, the above code does not work. I think I will try the JSON solution.

Comment: The chart is not displaying. I am using `data.addRow([d, ${reading.temperature}]);`. How can I debug this? I don't know Javascript at all, unfortunately.

Comment: Just look in generated HTML output if JSTL has done its job the expected way. If it did, then the problem is beyond JSP/JSTL and you'd have had exactly the same problem when using a hardcoded JS variable.

Comment: I am displaying the contents of `results` in a table and just noticed that time time got a `.0` at the end. Maybe that's the case, or should I change the pattern in `formatDate`?

Comment: Check the generated HTML output instead of guessing based on the browser's interpretation and presentation. Rightclick page, *View Source*.

Comment: In the HTML output, I see: `var d = new Date("2015-10-14T21:05:22.0");
                data.addRow([d,5.0]);`

Comment: Then JSTL has properly done its job as to printing/formatting the JS date variable and your new problem is beyond the scope of the question. Just press [Ask Question] button in right top if you can't figure out it.